# How can Floats and Symbols have immediate value?

Tags: ruby, unsigned-integer

I was informed by a fellow StackOverflow user that `Float`s now have immediate value in Ruby. However, I am confused as to how this is implemented.

I am also confused as to how `Symbol`s can have immediate value.

I understand that objects with immediate value are objects who's entire state information can be encapsulated into an `unsigned long` C variable called `VALUE`.

I can intuitively understand how this would be possible when considering small integers(`Fixnum`s), and trivial things like `true` `false` `nil` etc.

But, with no length restriction on `Float`s and `Symbol`s, how can these objects be represented without their own structs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a Float does a length restriction - a Float is basically a native double precision floating point value, i.e. 64 bits. That's still too much though, so a Float is an immediate value only if the mantissa is not too big (you can see the exact condition [here](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/include/ruby/ruby.h#369)).

As for symbols, there is a data structure enumerating all created symbols, so they can be referred to as offsets into that table (on ruby 2.2 only some symbols are like this - those that aren't are "normal", garbage collectible objects).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the treatment of symbols in v2.2 (or point me to a reference)?

Comment: See http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/authorNari/symbol-gc for example, but the short version is the symbols are mostly garbage collectable in 2.2

Comment: WOW! that must take up a lot of space. I thought that the entire point of trying to encapsulate state in a single variable was to avoid keeping giant tables. Are symbols just treated this way so comparison can be done faster?

Comment: @LukeP fast comparisons plus I think c level code needing these immutable and unique identifiers for things. A big advantage of these unmediates is not having to keep instantiating (and then garbage collecting) the same objects over and over again.

Comment: Again, regarding symbols, Is there just some constant that's created at run time that contains the address of the struct that ruby knows to check?

Comment: Not in the ruby sense, but there are C data structures containing all the static (non collectable) symbols